# Set Back Button Title on Xamarin Forms C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

im quite new to c# and Xamarin and I've just encountered a problem. I can't seem to be able to set the back button title on a navigation page. Ive tried using the static SetBackButtonTitle method but it does not seem to set the back button to the title I want which is 
'Test' but instead its giving me the 'default' title which is "Back".

```
        // The root page of your application
        var content = new ContentPage();


        var CompanyName = new Label();
        CompanyName.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        CompanyName.Text = "Test";

        var NextPage = new Button();
        NextPage.Text = "Next Page";
        NextPage.Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Large);
        NextPage.BorderWidth = 1;
        NextPage.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
        NextPage.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;

        var layout = new StackLayout();
        layout.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
        layout.Children.Add(CompanyName);
        layout.Children.Add(NextPage);

        content.Content = layout;

        var content2 = new ContentPage();

        var navigation = new NavigationPage(content);
        NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(navigation,true);
        NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(navigation,"Test");

        NextPage.Clicked += NextPageClicked;
        async  void NextPageClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await navigation.PushAsync(content2);
        }

        MainPage = navigation;



    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the back button's title(at the left in the navigation bar) in the second page, you should call the method [SetBackButtonTitle](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle/p/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject/System.String/) with first page as parameter. So please modify `NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(navigation,"Test");` to `NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(content,"Test");`

Answer (score 0):

For those who use Xamarin.Forms WPF if you want to change back button title you can do this:

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        Title = "";
    }

protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        Title = "MyTitle";
    }
```